# RHEL7 のスタティックルーティング設定について

Tags: linux, rhel

RHEL7でスタティックルーティングを切るとき、

```
nmcli c m <connection name> +ipv4.routes "<ip address/prefix> <destination>"
```

や

```
ip r add
```

で設定することが推奨されていますが、特定のipに対するreject設定は可能でしょうか。
例)
192.168.100.0/24は192.168.100.1をdestinationとするが、
192.168.100.10/24のみ10.10.10.1をdestinationとする…等

routeコマンドではrejectオプションがありますが、RHEL7では非推奨のコマンドであると認識しております。
また、ネットマスクを細分化することでも実現はできますが、可読性の観点から避けたい現状です。

なるべくnmcliコマンドやipコマンドでの設定、あるいはほかの推奨された方法がありましたらご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 192.168.100.0/24は192.168.100.1をdestinationとするが、
>   192.168.100.10/24のみ10.10.10.1をdestinationとする…等

192.168.100.0/24と192.168.100.10/24はルーティングを考える上では同じ宛先になるので

192.168.100.0/24は192.168.100.1をdestinationとするが、
192.168.100.10/**32**のみ10.10.10.1をdestinationとする…等

だとして考えます。

一般的にルーティングテーブルは最長一致で検索されるので、ルーティングテーブルに

- 192.168.100.0/24
- 192.168.100.10/32

のエントリがあれば、192.168.100.10宛てのルーティングには後者が使われます。もちろん、192.168.100.10以外の192.168.100.0/24には前者が使われます。ですので、単純に両方のルーティングを定義すればよいです。

Answer (score 1):

「`192.168.100.10/32`」でルーティングを追加してあげると、期待通りの動作を行うと思います。

＃ネットマスク長が長い(32に近い)方が基本的に優先されます。